# How can I get a file to use it in other command in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to make it like this. Below is the code.
I use vlc module a make a program that can play a song when you select it using python tkinter filedialog.

```
def select_file():
    filetypes = (
     ('mp3 files', '*.mp3'),)

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Select audio', initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)
def play():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
    p.play()
    time.sleep(60)
#play button
play_button = tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=play)
play_button.place(x=20, y=10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the rest of the answer, I would like to preface that [global variables can be dangerous if you are not careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil). With that being said, you could use a global variable for this. Here is a simple example of utilising a global variable with tkinter.

```
import tkinter

changing_value = 0
def change():
    global changing_value
    changing_value += 1

def printer():
    print(changing_value)
window = tkinter.Tk()
change_button = tkinter.Button(window, command=change, text="Change")
change_button.pack()
print_button = tkinter.Button(window, command=printer, text="Print")
print_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

As you may have noticed, I only declared `changing_value` as `global` in `change()`. This is since variable assignments would normally create a local scope value that is then lost when the function scope ends. Declaring it a global variable allows it to change the variable in the global scope, thus allowing the value used by `printer()` to change since it accesses the global scope variable by default. Something to consider is how to handle the value before one is initially assigned, that may be an issue if you don't have a default and the function which uses the value could be invoked before the one assigning it.

An alternative is using a mutable object and changing/accessing the value stored in the mutable object, but in my opinion that is just global variables with extra steps.

Applying the example to yours:

```
def select_file():
    global filename
    filetypes = (
     ('mp3 files', '*.mp3'),)

    filename = fd.askopenfilename(
        title='Select audio', initialdir='/',
        filetypes=filetypes)
def play():
    p = vlc.MediaPlayer(filename)
    p.play()
    time.sleep(60)
#play button
play_button = tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=play)
play_button.place(x=20, y=10)
```

Comment: I used the second one you show thanks!

Comment: Well, the first and the second are the same solution, the first is just a "proof of concept", while the second applies the concept to your scenario. Either way, glad I could help.